# Unable to have remote connections to a digital ocean redis service component

Tags: docker, redis, digital-ocean

I am trying to migrate to the new digital ocean app platform there however i am facing an issue deploying a redis instance and allowing remote connection.

my docker image is [here](https://github.com/grainer/docker-redis)

I have changed few things in the redis config file:

1 - the binding

```
bind 0.0.0.0
```

2 - disabled the protection

```
protected-mode no
```

the default port 6379 is exposed in the component and the component is listening to a specific route however the other component or even my local machine is enable to connect to that redis instance.

when i try:

```
redis-cli -h https://xxxx.ondigitalocean.app/docker-redis -p 6379 ping
```

i receive the following error:

```
Could not connect to Redis at 127.0.0.1:6379: Connection refused
```

I am not sure how to solve this issue or debug it for that matter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today Digitalocean app platform service component only exposes HTTPS at this time. they might expose more protocols in the future. in the meantime the solution is to use a normal droplet and setup a redis db there or use their reids managed db.